# Ubuntu Wordpress server tutorial error

Tags: apache2, sed

I am going through the WordPress installation tutorial [from Ubuntu Tutorials](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#6-configure-wordpress-to-connect-to-the-database) and I have typed this command as part of Step 6:

```
sudo -u www-data sed -i ‘s/database_name_here/wordpress’ /srv/www/wordpress/wp-config.php
```

And I get the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 30: undetermined ‘s’ command
```

Please help I cannot find anyone else having the same issue.

Comment: See the answer @matigo. If you copy/paste from the tutorial you should not get these syntax issues. With commands that need to be changed, copy first to a notepad or text editor

Comment: How can I copy paste when I’m doing this on a copy of Ubuntu server

Answer (score 2):

You will want to make sure that the quote in your command is not a "curly quote", like the ones in the command you shared; `’` and `'` mean different things.

However, you can simplify this for yourself by skipping the three `sed` commands they suggest and just opening the file for editing, which they ask you to do anyway:

```
sudo -u www-data nano /srv/www/wordpress/wp-config.php
```

In the file, you can replace `database_name_here` with your proper database name, `username_here` with the MySQL account name, and `password_here` with the MySQL account password. Remember that you cannot use `root` as the account name, so a proper WordPress-specific account will be needed.

In the event you need to configure these in MySQL, you can do this:

1. Connect to MySQL as an administrator. For example:

   ```
   sudo mysql
   ```
2. Create the database if it does not already exist:

   ```
   CREATE DATABASE `words` DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
   ```
3. Create a user account that WordPress can use:

   ```
   CREATE USER 'wpress'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'superSecretPassword!123';
   ```
4. Grant permissions to the WordPress database, including the ability to create new tables:

   ```
   GRANT ALL ON `words`.* TO 'wpress'@'localhost';
   ```

Be sure to replace the name of the database, the user account, and the password with ones that you would prefer. These values should match the values in your `wp-config.php` file.

Comment: I did as you suggested and then on step 7 I had to use another computer on the same network to go to the http://‘server IP address’ and it says error establishing a database connection

Comment: Have you created a MySQL user and an empty database for Wordpress? Was the user given access to the database?

Comment: I know the database is there because I went to create it again and it said it already existed but I did the same for the Wordpress user and it didn’t say it already existed it just said Query OK, 0 rows affected

Comment: I tried to create a user with a different name and got the same output. Does this mean my user was not created? And if so why not? I did it exactly like the tutorial.

Comment: I have updated the answer to show the steps you’ll need to follow for MySQL. Some you have likely done, but all are required.

Comment: Thank you I will try this tomorrow and update the post after.